# Camera js Web App unable to get camera feed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website that streams the user's webcam back to them. My browser shows an icon that indicates that the website is using my camera but there is no feed on my website. 
The package used: https://franticbomb.github.io/Camera-Web-App/

Here is only the js part

```
(function() {
  var video = document.getElementById("video"),
    vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  navigator.getMedia =
    navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia;

  // Capture video
  navigator.getMedia(
    {
      video: true,
      audio: false
    },
    function(stream) {
      video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.play();
    },
    function(error) {
      // An error occured
      // error.code
    }
  );
})();
```

I hope to display the camera feed back to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is completely outdated...

First, `navigator.getUserMedia` has been deprecated in favor of Promise based [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia).

So your first part should look like

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: false
}).then(function(stream) {
 ...
```

But that's not what is blocking your script from working.
If you did open your Browser's web-console, you probably would have found a message along the lines of

> *Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.*

That is because we cannot create blob-URLs from MediaStreams anymore. Instead, you should use the [`srcObject` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject) of your HTMLMediaElement:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: false
}).then(function(stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  return video.play();
});
```